# PHP passing data from 1 page to another page

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I pass id from 1st page to 2nd page?

In 1st Page I have query out my table

```
1st table: userdetails
            userID
            Username
            Email
            Address
            NationalID
            View More
```

In 2nd Page I need to mix 2 table into 1

```
2nd table: userimage
imageID
UserID
imageupload
```

For view more is not from my table is from this code.

```
<?php echo "<a href='userdetails.php?id=".$result['userID']."'>"?> View More </td>
```

Below is my 2nd page code

```
 $sql = "SELECT userdetails.imageupload
FROM userdetails
INNER JOIN user ON userdetails.memberpostID = user.memberpostID";

  $query = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
```

And this is the output on 2nd page

```
<?php
while($result=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
DATA OUTPUT 
}
```

But the output always show all data from userimage

Question that I want:
I wanted that if user click on  "VIEW MORE" on userID 1 , it will show userID details + imageupload on my 2nd page.

Comment: Your second page is missing a where clause.. where userID is equalt to the GET['id']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `userID` to the query.

```
$userID = $_GET['id'];
```

**WRONG WAY**

```
$sql = "SELECT userdetails.imageupload
        FROM userdetails
        INNER JOIN user ON userdetails.memberpostID = user.memberpostID WHERE userdetails.userID='".$userID."'";
```

**CORRECT WAY**

```
$sql = "SELECT userdetails.imageupload
    FROM userdetails
    INNER JOIN user ON userdetails.memberpostID = user.memberpostID WHERE userdetails.userID=:userID";

$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':userID' => $userID));
```

Note: User parameterized query to pass in the userID from the `$_GET` request to prevent SQL Injection. Don't concatenate variables, instead bind the parameters.

Comment: i don't understand on this, for the GET[userID] , where should i put ? before $sql code ?

Comment: Check the revised answer please.

Comment: okay fixed the problem , but mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: My bad. I have missed the $_GET param name. Check the refined answer.

Comment: You're preventing SQL Injections by parameterizing the parameters, not XSS.